# POST Request does not show any value in node JS

Tags: node.js, express, google-apps-script

I'm trying to send a post request to my node js server through google app script, but the received data is {}.

I tried sending a Post through zapier and postman, zapier will work if I set the payload type to "form" and postman will work if I set the body as x-www-form-urlencoded.

Any idea to make it work on google app script ?

[image]

Comment: I think that your showing script is Google Apps Script. But, your tag is `node.js`. Do you want to convert Google Apps Script to Node.js? If you want to modify your Google Apps Script, can you provide the official document of the API you want to use? Unfortunately, I cannot know the specification of the API you want to use. I apologize for this.

Comment: Hi Tanaike sorry if my question is not clear, I'm trying to send a post request from google app script to a node js server

Comment: Thank you for your reply. From `if my question is not clear, I'm trying to send a post request from google app script to a node js server`, I understand that you want to request using Google Apps Script. In that case, I think that it is required to know the specification of the request to the server you want to use. So I asked about the document of the API you want to use. I deeply apologize that I have no information about the API you want to use.

Comment: Here is the full code I'm trying to make, I don't have the API docs since this is just a standard POST.
App Script : https://pastebin.pl/view/8c6535ae
Node JS Server : https://pastebin.pl/view/bb60c197

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var requestOptions = {
  "method" : "post",
  "contentType" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "body" : payload
  //"body" : payload,

}
```

#### To:

```
var requestOptions = {
  "method": "post",
  "payload": payload
};
```

- Property of `body` is not existing in UrlFetchApp.
- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the default content type.
- When the request of this modification is run, `payload` is requested as the form data.

#### Note:

- As the additional information, in your server-side of Node.js, if `app.use(bodyParser.json());` is used, it is required to request as `application/json` as follows. Please be careful about this.

  ```
    var requestOptions = {
      "method": "post",
      "payload": JSON.stringify(payload),
      "contentType": "application/json"
    };
  ```

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks a lot I tried the modification that you suggested and it works. Appreciate your help thanks :)

Comment: @Michael Andreas Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you loaded json and urlencoded in your node server?

```js
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended:true
}));
  
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
  
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    res.send("Request received");
   
    
    
    console.log(req.body)
  
    //client.sendMessage(WANumber, Message);
    //console.log(nama);


    
    
  
});
  
app.listen(5555, function(){
  console.log("server is running on port 5555");
})

Comment: Yes @roicou this is the full node server code

Comment: This is the response if I use zapier / postman to send post : { ad: 'asd' } work well sama as body

Comment: But if i use the app script the body become {} without anything inside it